# How do I (or is it possible to) create Google Cloud Run Capacity settings using Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run

I am a Terraform newbie but I have done a lot of research and cannot find an answer.  I have no problem creating a Cloud Run instance using a simple Terraform file.  I can set environmental variables and secrets with no problems.  However, I cannot figure out how to create other settings such as "Memory allocated", "CPU allocated", etc.
[image]

My terraform file looks like:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "myproject" {  
project  ="myproject" 
name     = "cloud-run-name"  
location = "us-east1"


template {
 spec {
  containers {
    image = "gcr.io/myproject/image"

   env {
      name = "VARIABLE1"
      value = "variable1"
    }
    env {
      name = "VARIABLE2"
      value = "variable1"
    }
   
  }
}
}

traffic {
percent         = 100
latest_revision = true
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Memory/CPU goes under template > spec > containers > resources. Timeout and concurrency under template > spec.

Here is an example:

```
template {
  spec {
    container_concurrency = var.concurrency
    timeout_seconds = var.timeout

    containers {
      image = "gcr.io/myproject/image"

      ports {
        container_port = var.port
      }

      resources {
        limits = {
          cpu = "2m"
          memory = "8000Mi"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  So, I think I get it now.  I can find the arguments at: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service  and find where they are placed by looking at a Cloud Run yaml file for a previously built container.  Correct?

Comment: That would be a way to go for sure. Looking at a previous yaml you would have a full picture of where things are placed. Terraform docs won't give an example of all fields but you have a descriptive information on what it does and where it should be placed.

Comment: Very weird to find this information in SO and not a single example in Terraform GCP docs https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service Thank you.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this, `cpu = "2m"` means allocate 2 millicpus, or 0.2% of one CPU. If you want two CPUs, set `cpu = "2.0"`.